# WooCommerce Get Order Item Quantity For Multiple Orders / Bulk Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found this code on another page.

```
function jdr_get_orders_ids_from_product_id( $product_id, $orders_statuses = [ 'wc-completed' ] ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Define HERE the orders status to include in  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==
    $orders_statuses = "'" . implode( "', '", $orders_statuses ) . "'";

    # Get All defined statuses Orders IDs for a defined product ID (or variation ID)
    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim,
             {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi,
             {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        WHERE  woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        AND woi.order_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
        ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC"
    );
}
```

Using that I can find the $order_ids for any order than contains the specific $product_id.

However, I want to go one step further and get the quantity for each of these specific products inside the order.

We can do this using a couple custom functions like so:

```
function jdr_qty_sold_by_product_id( $product_id ) {
  $qty = 0;
  foreach( jdr_get_orders_ids_from_product_id( $product_id ) as $order_id )
    $qty = $qty + jdr_get_order_item_qty( $order_id, $product_id );
  return $qty;
}

function jdr_get_order_item_qty( $order_id, $product_id ) {
    $_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ($_order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
      $product = $item_data->get_product();
      if ( $product->get_id() == $product_id )
        return $item_data->get_quantity();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this requires looping through each order and each item, which takes a long time to load on pages where this function is needed (100+ orders).

I'm wondering if there is a SQL solution similar to the first function?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution:

```
function jdr_qty_sold_by_product_id( $product_id ) {
  global $wpdb;

  $data = jdr_get_orders_ids_and_item_ids_from_product_id( $product_id );

  $order_item_ids = array_map(function ($obj) { return $obj->order_item_id; }, $data);

  $order_item_ids = "'" . implode( "', '", $order_item_ids ) . "'";

  return $wpdb->get_var( "
      SELECT sum(meta_value)
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta
      WHERE order_item_id IN ( $order_item_ids )
      AND meta_key = '_qty'"
  );
}
```

After I edited the other function to include item_ids:

```
function jdr_get_orders_ids_and_item_ids_from_product_id( $product_id, $orders_statuses = [ 'wc-completed' ] ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $orders_statuses = "'" . implode( "', '", $orders_statuses ) . "'";

    return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id, woi.order_item_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim,
             {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi,
             {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        WHERE  woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        AND woi.order_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
        ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC"
    );
}
```